# NPM install fails with node-gyp after upgrading node to version 18

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, single-page-application

After upgrading nodejs to v16 and above fails to compile angular SPA which had no issue earlier.

Resolve issue with angular SPA compile npm instal

Answer (score 0):

Either downgrade nodejs to 14.11 which will resolve issue by installing chromium for node-sass.